# Assigning an input variable to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to assign an input variable to a dictionary this is what I have so far:

```
diction = {
           "name" : "john",
           "jobs" : ['police', 'mailman']
       }

chooseJob = input("Choose job: ")

if chooseJob == 'police' or chooseJob == 'mailman':
    print(diction['jobs'][chooseJob])
else:
    print("John doesn't have that job")
```

I type "police" into the input section and it outputs TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What is the expected output here? What do you want the final dictionary to look like?

Comment: I don't understand what you *want* `diction['jobs'][chooseJob]` to evaluate to, and *why*. I also don't understand why you titled this "Assigning an input variable to python dictionary"; do you want to *change* the contents of `diction`, or not?

Comment: Maybe you get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`?

Comment: It's a fairy simple error. I'd suggest you familiarize with `pdb`

Comment: I would have recommended a nested dictionary with jobs and check if names are in the diction with diction.keys()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `job` variable is list type and you can assign/read list with string values instead you have to give index position in which you want to insert/read the data.

try this..

```
diction = {
       "name" : "john",
       "jobs" : ['police', 'mailman']
   }

chooseJob = input("Choose job: ")

if chooseJob == 'police':
    print(diction['jobs'][0])
elif chooseJob == 'mailman':
    print(diction['jobs'][1])
else:
    print("John doesn't have that job")`
```

Answer (score 0):

`diction['jobs']` returns a list, and a list can only have integers inside these brackets `diction['jobs'][chooseJob]`, because it's the index of the list.

Maybe this is what you meant to do:

```
diction = {
           "name" : "john",
           "jobs" : ['police', 'mailman']
       }

chooseJob = input("Choose job: ")

if chooseJob == 'police' or chooseJob == 'mailman':
    print(chooseJob)
else:
    print("John doesn't have that job")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far have addressed the syntax issues with your code but really don't address the logic issues.  I.e. they really don't use the dictionary in an meaningful way.  (I.e. they duplicate the data in the dictionary in the code.)  I would expect your data and code to play out more like:

```
dictionary = {
    'name' : "John",
    'jobs' : ['police', 'mailman']
    }

chooseJob = input("Choose job: ")

if chooseJob in dictionary['jobs']:
    print(dictionary['name'], "does have that job!")
else:
    print(dictionary['name'], "doesn't have that job.")
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Choose job: police
John does have that job!
> python3 test.py
Choose job: mailman
John does have that job!
> python3 test.py
Choose job: garbageman
John doesn't have that job.
>
```